# Is Alia kwisatz haderach as well?

Tags: dune

If bene gesserit mothers were unable to unlock generic memory of their male predecessors, how Alia can possibly be possessed by Baron Harkonnen?

Is Alia kwisatz haderach then?

How is this possible, if kwisatz haderach suppose to be male?

Comment: Shes an an abomination

Comment: Yes, I know :) but then abominations are kwisatz haderach females???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Yes and no (kinda).

The primary goal of the Bene Gesserit breeding program was to create a *male* that was capable of accessing both the female memories and those that were barred to them, found in the "place that they can't go" (e.g. male source memories) giving them full access to both the past and reliable visions of the future.

> *That is the place where we cannot look, she thought. There is the
>   place the Reverend Mothers are so reluctant to mention–the place where
>   only a Kwisatz Haderach may look.*

Alia is *born capable* of accessing those memories (as evidenced by her possession by the Baron Harkonnen), but it's certainly arguable that the Bene Gesserit didn't actually know what they were going to get with the Kwisatz Harderach, not just a male Bene Gesserit but also a powerful being capable of twisting the timelines to their own advantage, something that Alia never really mastered due to her gender and personal weaknesses.

> *“Try your tricks on me, old witch,” Paul said. “Where’s your gom
>   jabbar? **Try looking into that place where you dare not look! You’ll
>   find me there staring out at you!”***

Note that Leto II and Ghanima also had this ability but, again, neither really fit the mantle of the Kwisatz Haderach since they're both *born* with this ability rather than gaining it through the spice trance.

Comment: More specifically, the three of them are pre-born.

Comment: Is it correct to say that Alia have some of alilities of kwisatz haderach, but she is definitely not kwisatz haderach, because she lacks some other desired abilities, for example she is not male and she is not at important position?

Comment: @Nick - Her position isn't especially relevant (the Tleilaxu cloned up a Kwisatz Haderach of their own, apparently) but what's important is that she never gained the ability to master the spice-visions. Her view of the future was always severely clouded and imperfect, little better than that of a Guild Steersman.

Answer (score 1):

The Kwisatz Haderach was the culmination of a 10,000 years long Bene Gesserit breeding programme. Their goal to make a male capable of being essentially a male Bene Gesserit and thus able to see the Male ancestral side memories. It was a name for a Unique individual.

Alia, Leto II, and others, preborn/not who also had this ability, let the term evolve passed a unique individual, but into a term that applied to anyone with male ancestral memories. Paul was the *true* Kwisatz Haderach due to the precise breeding program, and was the end goal of the project.

Comment: Their breading programme? To see if they can create a yeasty saviour?

Comment: yes they wanted to create the optimal pop star. such as a pitbull to there kesha https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHUbLv4ThOo

Comment: Paul was a generation early and can do stuff that the Bene Gesserit never imagined. It's arguable that they never got their KH

Comment: @Valorum ah, but he was a generation early, because Jessica didn't follow the breeding plan. 1 generation off out of 10,000 years isnt bad

Comment: Swing and a miss for the Bene Gesserit. They ended up with a god they didn't believe in and 3500 years of servitude for their troubles.

Comment: It is doubtful if Paul can be referred to as Kwisatz Haderach as he himself in conversation with his mother says he is "something else, a freak"